# If corr(A,B) = x and corr(B,C) = y, what is corr(A,C)?

Tags: probability, correlation

If I know the correlation between two pairs of random variables (A,B) and (B,C), can I determine the correlation of the pair (A,C)? If not, can I at least constrain it to some range?

I'm interesting in generating a covariance matrix where certain pairwise correlation values are determined, and the rest are as small (i.e. close to 0) as possible.

Comment: How do you define "as small as possible"? Depending on how you define that, you can probably write down a semidefinite program for generating such a covariance matrix.

Comment: I mean as close to zero as possible. Fixed.

Comment: you have a vector of values (the entries of the matrix). You still need to define how "close to zero" is for that vector of values. For example, if you chose to minimize the 1-norm of the entries of the matrix, you'd get a different solution than if you minimized the 2-norm. or used a different criterion. For example, if the missing entries were 1.5, 1.5, and 1, 2, which would you say is smaller? why?

Comment: Note that "having positive correlation" is not a transitive relation.  e.g., consider $X,Y,Z$ where $X,Z$ are iid and $Y = X+Z$.  Then $X,Y$ are correlated and $Y,Z$ are correlated but $X,Z$ are not.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately no, we cannot determine $\rho_{AC}$ given just $\rho_{AB}$ and $\rho_{BC}$. You can derive the theoretical bounds
\begin{align*}
\rho_{AC} \ge \max\{2(\rho_{AB} + \rho_{BC}) - 3, 2\rho_{AB}\rho_{BC} - 1\} 
\end{align*}
**Proof**. Some notation. I let $\sigma_{AB} = \text{Cov}(A,B)$ and $\sigma_A^2 = \text{Var}(A)$.

Let's first prove $\rho_{AC} \ge 2(\rho_{AB} + \rho_{BC}) - 3$. Recall the identity
\begin{align*}
2 E[X^2] + 2E[Y^2] = E[(X+Y)^2] + E[(X-Y)^2]
\end{align*}
hence $2E[Y^2] \le E[(X+Y)^2] + E[(X-Y)^2]$. Set 
\begin{align*}
X = \widetilde{B} - (\widetilde{A} + \widetilde{C})/2 \quad \text{and} \quad Y =
 (\widetilde{A} - \widetilde{C})/2
\end{align*}
where $\widetilde{C} = (C - E[C])/\sigma_C$, the normalized random variable, and similarly for $\widetilde{A}, \widetilde{B}$. Upon substitution and simplification, we get
\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{2}(2 - 2\rho_{AC}) \le (2 - 2\rho_{AB}) + (2 - 2\rho_{BC}) \iff \rho_{AC} \ge 2(\rho_{AB} + \rho_{BC}) - 3
\end{align*}
To prove $\rho_{AC} \ge 2\rho_{AB}\rho_{BC} - 1$, consider the random variable
\begin{align*}
W = 2 \frac{\sigma_{AB}}{\sigma_B^2}B - A
\end{align*}
We can verify $\sigma_W^2 = \sigma_A^2$, and hence $\sigma_{WC} \le \sigma_{W}\sigma_{C} = \sigma_ A \sigma_C$ by the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality. On the other hand, you may compute
\begin{align*}
\sigma_{WC} = 2 \frac{\sigma_{AB}}{\sigma_B^2}\sigma_{BC} - \sigma_{AC}
\end{align*}
Reorganizing all this, we prove $\rho_{AC} \ge 2\rho_{AB}\rho_{BC} - 1$.

Comment: Doesn't there have to be an upper bound as well?

Comment: Of course, $\rho_{AC} \le 1$, and we can't do any better. It is quite easy to construct $\rho_{AC} = 1$ while $\rho_{AB}$ and $\rho_{BC}$ are quite arbitrary; for example, take $A = C$ almost surely, and $B$ could be completely positively correlated, uncorrelated, or completely negatively correlated with $A$ (and, by extension, $C$).

Comment: If $ \rho_{AB} = 0.9 $ and $ \rho_{BC} = -0.9 $, There seems to be an upper bound well below 0 for what $ \rho_{AC} $ can be. I'm getting that the covariance matrix defined by these values (assuming unit variance) is not positive semi-definite.

Comment: Is this a well-known inequality? Is there a reference?

Comment: @JairTaylor Is that a question for me, or Tom?

Comment: @Evan Anyone who knows the answer... but, I was referring to Tom's interesting inequality in the post.

Comment: @Evan Yes, with your example, the bounds are obviously quite nonsensical. I guess if you wanted to derive upper bounds as well, you could switch the roles of $A, B, C$ around and rearrange in targetting a bound for $\rho_{AC}$. Since your utmost concern is having your covariance matrix by positive semi-definite, no general result exists AFAIK. You might try simulating with your specific cases to derive the space of all possible matrices.

Comment: @JairTaylor I don't think these are bounds that quite well-known. The bound $\rho_{AC} \ge 2 \rho_{AB}\rho_{BC} -  1$ is a generalization, through some re-ordering of the algebra, of Problem 4.4 from Steele's "The Cauchy-Schwarz Master Class" textbook.The other bound was something I happened upon some time ago.

Comment: @TomChen Thanks!  It looks like a very useful inequality to keep in mind.

Comment: I find the notation a bit confusing. After you define, $X,Y$, when you use notation $A,B,C$ are you really referring to $\tilde{A}, \tilde{B}, \tilde{C}$?